# Law of large numbers and standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, law-of-large-numbers

In wikipedia, the law of large numbers is defined as follows :

*"The **average** of the results obtained from a large number of trials should be close to the expected value and tends to become closer to the expected value as more trials are performed."*

Meanwhile, because of the convergence in probability(or the weak law of large numbers), we can infer that when n - the sample size - is very big, the observed distribution would converge to probability distribution of an event. In this sense, then, it is evident that the obtained mean would converge to the actual mean, as it is mentioned in Wikipedia above.

My remaining doubt is that because the probability of a random variable converges as sample size increases, would it be okay to state that the observed **standard deviation** also converges to the actual standard deviation - like it was the case with averages. Or we might see it in a slightly different perspective : because sample standard deviation estimator is consistent, we can expect that it would converge to the actual standard deviation.

I noticed that in elaborating the law of large numbers most documents mention averages but not standard deviation, and just wanted make sure why.

Comment: Is the post asking whether or not $s\overset{\mathbb P}{\to}\sigma? $

Comment: Convergence of an arbitrary sequence of random numbers in probability does not imply the means converge: that is what makes the WLLN special.  However, the WLLN immediately implies both the means and the mean squares converge, whence the SD (a continuous function of those quantities) must converge to the SD of the underlying distribution.